# Nav menu with pure CSS

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have a HTML menu

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggler">
        <label for="toggler"><div id="menu-icon">
            <div class="menu-icon-bar"></div>
            <div class="menu-icon-bar"></div>
            <div class="menu-icon-bar"></div>
        </div></label>
        <nav id="navbar">
            <h1 class="main-menu-header">CSS Layout Documentation</h1>
            <a href="#main-doc" class="nav-link">Home</a>
            <a href="index.html#Normal_Flow" class="nav-link">Normal flow</a>
            <a href="#The_display_property" class="nav-link">The display property</a>
            <a href="#flexbox" class="nav-link">Flexbox</a>
            <a href="#Grid_Layout" class="nav-link">Grid layout</a>
            <a href="#Floats" class="nav-link">Floats</a>
            <a href="#Positioning_techniques" class="nav-link">Positioning techniques</a>
            <a href="#Table_layout" class="nav-link">Table layout</a>
            <a href="#Multi-column_layout" class="nav-link">Multi-column layout</a>
        </nav>
```

and I use toggler to show and hide navbar with :checked pseudo class.

I position menu absolutely or fixed full screen.

As you can see my href links lead to the same page (different sections).

Using pure CSS, is it possible to hide navbar on link click without using any js?  I don't want to create input checkbox for every a link I have. Is this possible at all?

Comment: What if you wrap entire the navbar in a new label for toggler?

Comment: so you want the navbar be hidden when the checkbox #toggler is checked and shown when its unchecked? i am not quite sure what u wanna do bro. can you explain better? or give a example with using js?

Comment: On a general note: Don’t get so fixated on “pure CSS” all the time. Many things that _are_ possible using CSS without any additional scripting when it comes to stuff like this, have terrible usability.

Comment: It _would_ be possible here, if you put your navigation at the end of your HTML, _after_ those elements you are jumping to with the anchors, and all those elements having those IDs could be placed on a level where they are _siblings_ of the `#navbar` element. Then you could use `:target` in combination with the general sibling combinator to hide the navigation.

Comment: The idea of wrapping entire navbar into label probably might work, I'll try it, thank you Ali Sheikhpour. @CBroe, thanks for noting, it's just I get such pre-requisite, not that I don't want to do it different way :)